# How to convert BeautifulSoup output to a python dictionary. Also need advise on the type of database useful in managing large data in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When i run the below python code using bs4, I receive the data which is already in dictionary format, how to i convert it in python dictionary or dataframe. in python.

```
headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}

r=requests.get(current_url, headers= headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
 <body>
  <pre style="word-wrap":break word; white-space: pre-wrap">
{"futuresPrice":18207.6,"iv":15.27,"lotsize":50,"optionchaindata":[{"CallDelta":"-","CallIV":"-","CallLTP":"-","CallVega":"-","PutDelta":-0.45,"PutIV":42.53,"PutLTP":1.85,"PutVega":39.87,"Strikes":15150.0,"index_x":"-","index_y":2.0,"name":""},{"CallDelta":"-","CallIV":"-","CallLTP":"-","CallVega":"-","PutDelta":-0.31,"PutIV":39.8,"PutLTP":1.15,"PutVega":28.51,"Strikes":15200.0,"index_x":"-","index_y":6.0,"name":""},{"CallDelta":0.0,"CallIV":0.0,"CallLTP":2700.0,"CallVega":0.0,"PutDelta":-0.57,"PutIV":38.49,"PutLTP":2.2,"PutVega":49.86,"Strikes":15500.0,"index_x":1.0,"index_y":10.0,"name":""},{"CallDelta":0.0,"CallIV":0.0,"CallLTP":2206.65,"CallVega":0.0,"PutDelta":-0.71,"PutIV":31.81,"PutLTP":2.3,"PutVega":60.4,"Strikes":16000.0,"index_x":3.0,"index_y":14.0,"name":""},{"CallDelta":"-","CallIV":"-","CallLTP":"-","CallVega":"-","PutDelta":-0.79,"PutIV":26.07,"PutLTP":2.1,"PutVega":66.0,"Strikes":16400.0,"index_x":"-","index_y":15.0,"name":""},{"CallDelta":"-","CallIV":"-","CallLTP":"-","CallVega":"-","PutDelta":-0.88,"PutIV":25.76,"PutLTP":2.35,"PutVega":72.89,"Strikes":16450.0,"index_x":"-","index_y":16.0,"name":""}
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that really the output? It doesn't appear to even be valid HTML, with no closing `</pre>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets suppose the string you got from the request is called str_in (in your case this is r.text). We can trim to the start and end of the json string in the response like this:

```py
# Make sure to add this import!
import json

# Finds the first occurrence of { and trims the string to it, and finds the last occurrence of } and trims the back to it.
response_trimmed = str_in[str_in.find("{"):str_in.rfind("}")+1]
# Turns the string into a dictionary 
response_dict = json.loads(response_trimmed)
```

Do however note that the response json is invalid (it is missing a `]}` at the end), so we will have to fix the json in order to load it into a dictionary correctly. Here's your code modified to correctly trim out the json section of the response and fix the invalid json:

```py
# Make sure to add this import!
import json

headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}

r=requests.get(current_url, headers= headers)
res_txt = r.text

# Finds the first occurrence of { and trims the string to it, and finds the last occurrence of } and trims the back to it.
res_trimmed = res_txt[res_txt.find("{"):res_txt.rfind("}")+1]
# Turns the string into a dictionary. The + "]}" fixes the broken json in the response.
res_dict= json.loads(res_trimmed + "]}")
print(res_dict)
```

If you'd like an example of this working, you can take a look here: https://onecompiler.com/python/3xnfzrrex

Comment: @shekharkilche No problem! I'm really glad it worked out for you! Good luck with the rest of your project!